# MessageBox error

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8-1

Tentei implementar o código abaixo em um projeto Windows Phone 8.1, o mesmo já havia sido implementado em Windows Forms com êxito.

O que devo alterar para que seja válido para WindowsPhone 8.1?

```
private void reset_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    const string message = "Voce deseja voltar o jogo ao seu estado normal ?";
    const string caption = "Reset";
    var result = MessageBox.Show(message, caption,
                                 MessageBoxButtons.YesNo,
                                 MessageBoxIcon.Question);

    if (result == DialogResult.No)
    {

    }
    else { this.Close(); /*re-estabeleçe valores*/ }

    }
```

Apresenta o seguinte erro:

> The name 'MessageBox' does not exist in the current context

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nas novas APIs do Windows Phone 8.1 você precisa utilizar o `await MessageDialog().ShowAsync()` do Windows.UI.Popups.
No seu caso, ficaria assim:

```
var mensagem = new MessageDialog("Sua mensagem");
await mensagem.ShowAsync();
```

Answer (score 2):

Windows Phone não é igual Windows Forms.
O seu código deve ficar alguma coisa próxima a isso:

```
private async void reset_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    const string message = "Voce deseja voltar o jogo ao seu estado normal ?";
    const string caption = "Reset";

    MessageBoxResult result = MessageBox.Show(message, caption, MessageBoxButton.OKCancel);

    if (result == MessageBoxResult.Cancel)
    {

    }
    else { this.Close(); /*re-estabeleçe valores*/ }

}
```

Tudo isso com:

```
using System.Windows;
```

no cabeçalho do arquivo.